# java project files not loaded when executing

Tags: java, eclipse, textures

I created a Java JOGL project for a friend, for his university assignment, and imported a few jpg files used for textures.

When application is started (I'm using Eclipse IDE), I get a bunch of errors, which all disappear when I use full path to texture files.

Where should I import those files? Do I need to set something in project prefs in order for this to work correctly?

Thx

Comment: ok, I found a solution. The files were supposed to go into project folder, and not into src or class.

Comment: @sleske: thx, i thought about it, but it sounded like cheating ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And here's an answer:

Turns out that files should be saved under the project folder, and not some subfolder.